# Не сохраняются настройки в Isolated Storage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

Здравствуйте, хочу сделать изменение шрифта в FixedHtmlTextBlock. И решил создать 2 разных Data Template, один по умолчанию (с размером шрифта 20), а другой будет выбираться в настройках (с размером 25). Проблема следующая: когда сохраняю увеличенный шрифт то при переходе на другую страницу и обратно - шрифт сохраняется увеличенным, а когда закрываю приложение и захожу снова, то настройка увеличенного шрифта не сохраняется.

Получение настройки:

```
public Section1Detail()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Размер текста
    if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("TextSize"))
    {
        Container.ItemTemplate = (DataTemplate)(IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["TextSize"]);
    }
}
```

Сохранение настройки:

```
Container.ItemTemplate = (DataTemplate)this.Resources["Large"];

IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings; 
if (!settings.Contains("TextSize"))
{
    settings.Add("TextSize", Container.ItemTemplate);
}
else 
{
    settings.Remove("TextSize");
    settings.Add("TextSize", Container.ItemTemplate);
}
settings.Save();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `IsolatedStorageSettings` можно сохранять только объекты сериализуемых типов. `DataTemplate` таковым не является. Поскольку вам нужно сохранять размер, то использование `DataTemplate` еще и несколько излишне. На вашем месте я бы сохранял в настройках сам размер как число.

P.S. Да, и при добавлении настройки достаточно вот так писать, все эти проверки и `Remove` не нужны:

```
settings["TextSize"] = textSize;
```

Comment: а не подскажете как в коде изменить размер шрифта в FixedHtmlTextBlock.У меня возникают затруднения потому, что FixedHtmlTextBlock находится в DataTemplate, а сам DataTemplate находится в PhoneApplicationPage.Resources

Comment: @MaxBazanov видимо, это какой-то кастомный контрол? В деталях могу ошибаться, но я бы попробовал так: 1) убрал DataTemplate из ресурсов (он там теперь не нужен), 2) обращался к свойству FontSize у контрола для сохранения и установки размера текста. Тут придется наладить взаимодействие между вью моделью и code behind.